# FQL: Facebook application php

Tags: php, facebook-fql

Hello I have implemented the following

```
$fql    =   "SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=" . $uid;
$param  =   array(
 'method'    => 'fql.query',
 'query'     => $fql,
 'callback'  => ''
);
$fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);
```

Now I need to fetch elements from `$fqlResult`. How should I do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can just iterate through the array returned by facebook:

```
$fqlResult   =   $this->facebook->api($param);
foreach($fqlResult as $result)
{
  print_r($result);
  print($result['name']);
}
```

Thanks for the code! I was looking for this way of making FQL's with the new library!

Answer (score 0):

You can also print the entire array in a convenient format (due to the pre tags) with the following function:

```
function d($array) {
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($array);
  echo '</pre>';
}

d($fqlResult);
```